# In bash how to strip the string

Tags: bash

I have a variable called input which is space separated, Where I want to strip string with colon and get the third element.

> ```
> input=a:b:c 1:2:3 x:y:z
>
> output=c 3 z
> ```

Comment: I'm sure you'll find tons of questions here on how to do this.

Comment: You might want to look at the man pages of `awk`, `cut` and `sed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can populate a BASH array with input string and then replace everything up to last colon:

```
input='a:b:c 1:2:3 x:y:z'
read -ra arr <<< "$input"

echo "${arr[@]/*:}"
c 3 z
```

Comment: Awesome, Can you please explain

Comment: `read -ra arr <<< "$input"` populates an array `arr` using your input string and then `"${arr[@]/*:}"` removes everything upto last `:` from each element.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=:).(?=\s|$)' <<< 'a:b:c 1:2:3 x:y:z' | paste -s -d ' '
c 3 z
```

`grep` searches for any char that has `:` behind it(using positive lookbehind assertion) and `\s`(whitespace) or `$` (end of line) after it(using positive look-ahead assertion).

For each of these chars we paste it serially(converting lines to rows with values) with delimiter as space.

Comment: Care to explain? :) It is not straightforward.

Comment: @JulienLopez added some :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for` loop and the [`cut` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html):

```
for values in $input; do
    echo "$values" | cut -d ':' -f 3
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo a:b:c 1:2:3 x:y:z | awk -F: '{print $3,$5,$7}' |awk '{print $1,$3,$5}'
```

OR

```
echo a:b:c 1:2:3 x:y:z | tr ':' ' ' |awk '{print $3,$6,$9}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo a:b:c 1:2:3 x:y:z | awk -F '[: ]' '{print $3,$6,$9}'
c 3 z
```

In order to print every third character in each field we have to use the delimiters.
In this case the most obvious one is colon but the space between the fields has to be considered as well. Then it becomes feasible to print every...